# Is there a crawler that increments views?

Tags: discussion

The number of views on some (not all) of my questions appear to increase at the same tempo.

This feels a bit suspicious, but could just be a coinsidence.

Wondering if there was a crawler job that could be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, viewcounter does not count webcrawlers.

Answer (score 4):

I think the viewcounter does not count webcrawlers, but there might be unknown webcrawlers that disguise themselves as regular users.